# vb.net How to file a user telegram id on a column of a data-table?

Tags: vb.net, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a database with my clients info and i need to send them notifications using following code

```
Public Function invia_messaggio(chat_id As String, testo As String) As String
    Dim ff As String = "/sendMessage"
    Dim urln As String
    pp = "?chat_id=" & chat_id & "&text=" & testo
    urln = urlt + ff + pp
    Dim RISP As String
    RISP = aurum.HttpPost(urln, "")
    Return RISP
End Function
```

How can I get chat id from client and file in my database? I could send them a button which they press and they link to a login form sending their chat id, is that possible? How can I do it?
Thx

Comment: Yeah, of course it's possible but you really have to give us a whole lot more info.  What sort of db, what is the structure of your db, what db technology  (Ado, EF, Othere) are you using.

Comment: Thanks Hursey but the question is not about the database which is Sql, the question is how to get the chat id from the client using a telegram API

Comment: Well, might I suggest you re work your question some then to be very explicit of exactly what your problem is.  You've said you want to get the chat_Id into the database, then said the database has nothing to do with it..  I know I'm struggling to understand what you problem is, the code snippet above, chat_id is passed in as a parameter so I don't see what the problem is.